# Django. 'string indices must be integers, not unicode'

Tags: django, django-admin

When I run this action in admin site (Send e-mail to selected people) i have error:

**string indices must be integers, not unicode django** on line: `[p.user_email])`

How to fix it?

```
from django.contrib import admin
from myproject.myapp.models import People
from django.core.mail import send_mail

def send_mail(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    for p in queryset:
        send_mail('People information', p.name, p.time, 'mymail@gmail.com'
    [p.user_email])
send_mail.short_description = u'Send e-mail to selected people'

class PeopleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'user_email','time')
    actions = [send_mail]

admin.site.register(People, PeopleAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you forgot the comma after `'mymail@gmail.com'`, so it's interpreting it as `'mymail@gmail.com'[p.user_email]`, as if you were trying to index the string literal.

Comment: Thanks. This fix it. Actually i have: send_mail() takes exactly 3 arguments (5 given) on line  [p.user_email])

Comment: @user1682273 : You've defined `send_mail(modeladmin, request, queryset)` and then called it from within itself.  Rename your `send_mail`, or import core.mail.send_mail as some other name. Also, you should mark an answer as accepted if it solved your problem, and open a new question for new, unrelated problems.

Comment: That's because the method definition is: `send_mail(subject, message, from_email, recipients)`. You've got two parameters where `message` should be.